problemas de incompatibilidad de Kotlin
tengo problemas con el archivo "build.gradle" a nivel de proyecto, al parecer me pide que actualize Kotlin, pero a pesar que puse la mas reciente aun persiste el error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\cisne\Documents\PROYECTOS\Android\Flutter\AppCobranza\cobranza\android\build.gradle' line: 16

What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '+', apply: false]



The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with a different version (1.7.10).




Hola Michel, bienvenido, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos. .

The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with a different version. ¿Revisaste el classpath?
